# Eclipse not finding android xml layout files in res/layout folder

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, android-layout, autocomplete

I changed the names of a couple of view items in one of my layout files, and suddenly my layout files (R.layout.*) and views (R.id.*) are getting redlined and not coming up in autocomplete.

I'm importing android.R.  But it was working just fine until I renamed the layout items.

Any suggestions?

I've tried refresh, clean, and restarting Eclipse already.

Edit: I changed my import to:

```
package com.example.techgadgets;
import com.example.techgadgets.R;
```

but still no go.

Comment: *I'm importing android.R*, you are importing the wrong one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure your changed XML resource files do not have any errors. If there are errors in a resource file, then the `aapt` tool will not create an R.java file for you.

In my experience, that is the most common reason for the issue you are seeing.

Comment: Well, I was not seeing any errors, but somehow found that I was attempting to use a property that was not allowed for that view. That solved the problem. Now I'm onto the next strange difficulty...

Answer (score 4):

As blackbelt says, you're importing `android.R` - you should be importing `my.package.R` instead, as this is the generated file that contains references to the entities in your `res` folder.